# Getting file name without the path in the binary with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I am using the preprocessor directive `__BASE_FILE__` in my C project built with GCC. The problem is that the binary built by two different computers must be identical, so the path can't appear in the binary file produced.

I can't find a way to shrink the string returned by `__BASE_FILE__` (that contains the full path to the file) during preprocessing. Is there a way to do that ?

This string is used inside a macro like this one :

```
#define MY_MACRO() \
{ \
    int file_name_size = sizeof(__BASE_NAME__); \
    char* file_name = __BASE_NAME__; \
    \
    a_function_that_use_these_variables(file_name, file_name_size); \
}
```

So I would like to have `__BASE_FILE__` that only contains the file name, not the path.

Comment: How about you add something like `-D__BASE_FILE_NAME__=$(notdir $<)` to the `$(CC)` recipes in the `Makefile`s (defining the base name of the first prerequisite as macro `__BASE_FILE_NAME__`)?

Comment: This solution works for me !

Answer (score 1):

> How about you add something like -D__BASE_FILE_NAME__=$(notdir $<) to the $(CC) recipes in the Makefiles (defining the base name of the first prerequisite as macro **BASE_FILE_NAME**)?

This solution works.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`strrchr`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strrchr) to find `'/'` or [`basename`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/basename) to grab the filename at *runtime*